# pandas matplot retrieve colors used by colormap stacked bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use the following line to draw a stacked bar graph from a dataframe using a specific color map *Set1*. I want to use the same set of colors that is used in this plot in another bar plot

```
pl=df.plot(ax=ax1, kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap="Set1", width=0.5)
```

Here is another plot where I want to be able to use exactly the same colors used from the first plot

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    ax2=row.plot(ax=ax2, kind='bar', color=#same colors used up, width=0.5
```

Comment: For me (Pandas version 0.23.1), `row.plot` has a `colormap=` argument.

Comment: it uses only the first color in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to construct the same color list from the color map as follows and use  that color list in both plots

```
    rng = np.arange(len(df.columns))/(len(df.columns))
    colors = plt.cm.Set1(rng)
    pl=df.plot(ax=ax1, kind='bar', stacked=True, color=colors, width=0.5)
    ax2=row.plot(ax=ax2, kind='bar', color=colors, width=0.5)
```